# Send Email with the body formatted

Tags: email, scheduled-apex, apex

...I am trying to send a single email in the finish part of the Batchable class where the body of the email is formatted. Basically, I want to populate the body with lists of Accounts previously batched in the execute part. Here is the code I have so far :

```
public Void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
{


    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String toAddress = 'email@email.co.uk'; //need to create this account in salesforce 
    mail.setReplyTo(''); //TODO
    mail.setSubject('Lists of Contacts created from the public Stuff Site');
    //loop over the list of cases
    for (Account acc : mapPSContact.values())
    {
        mail.setPlainTextBody('These are the List of Public Stuff accounts created on the System with thier customer enquiry information : ' + '\n' + 
            'Account : ' + acc + '\n' + 
            'Case : ' + '');
         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send one email with all the information in it you will need code that looks more like this:

```
public Void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String toAddress = 'email@email.co.uk'; //need to create this account in salesforce 
    mail.setReplyTo(''); //TODO
    mail.setSubject('Lists of Contacts created from the public Stuff Site');

    String body = 'These are the List of Public Stuff accounts created on the System'
           + ' with their customer enquiry information: ' + '\n';
    for (Account acc : mapPSContact.values())
    {
        // Pick out the various fields you want and add them to the body
        body += 'Account : ' + acc.Name + '\n';
        body += 'Enquiry Information : ' + '' + '\n';
    }

    mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

Note that you can also create a HTML email that gives you more control over formatting. And you should probably sort the Accounts by name so they are presented in a well defined order.